# In asp.net mvc3 on button submit, not causing action to be performed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am stuck when I am clicking the submit button. On clicking the submit button, Its not moving back to the HttpPost action.I am sharing my code.

**Controller:**
    public class AccountController : Controller
        {

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/LogOn
        public ActionResult UserLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserLogin(LogOn model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Compltete", model);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }


    }
```

**View:**

```
@model SanjiviniAnalytics.Models.LogOn

<h2>User Login</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {

```
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sign In</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

}
```

**Model:**

```
public class LogOn
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set;}
}
```

Can anyone please help me to find where I am going wrong?

Comment: So what happens when the button is clicked?  Is it calling the Get method again?

Comment: yes. it calls the get method everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `Controller` out of the form.. MVC doesn't require that you include the Controller part of a controller name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin","Account"))
```

Also, try specifying POST as the method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: I did Sir, But its not solving my problem.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin","Account", FormMethod.Post))
```

(Just saw Simon beat me to it:))

Answer (score 0):

As Simon said, the following will work. HttpPost action will take place from FormMethod.Post method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
```